# NoMethodError in MembersController#index undefined method `total_pages' for #<Micropost::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ffc26104288>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

The error output is:

```
NoMethodError in MembersController#index
undefined method `total_pages' for  #<Micropost::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ffc26104288>
```

Application trace is:

```
app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb__933429040368905157_70360748756160'
app/views/members/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_members_index_html_erb__2919315027143638402_70360970104820'
```

**Update:**

Source near error:

```
        arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
      else
        super # marked red
      end
    end
  end
```

**Additional info:**

`app/views/members/index.html.erb` renders two partials using another controller, `microposts_controller`.  So I'll show contents of both controllers and of the two partials.

```
# app/views/members/index.html.erb
<%= render 'shared/micropost_form', :locals => { :micropost => @micropost }  %>
<%= render 'shared/feed', :locals => { :feed_items => @feed_items } %>
```

MembersController

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.microposts
  end
end
```

micropost_controller.rb

```
# controllers/micropost_controller.rb

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to '/members'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render '/members'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || '/members'
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to '/members' if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

_micropost_form.html.erb

```
# shared/_micropost_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost (420 chars max)..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

_feed.html.erb

```
# shared/_feed.html.erb

<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: please update your answer with error trace

Comment: Maybe `micropost.created_at` returns `nil`? Though it would be strange for saved in DB micropost record.

Comment: what are the values of `from_time` and `to_time` ?

Comment: Modify the title, since the question is about something completely different than at the beginning. And show the line of code that is causing an error.

Comment: I have added the trace @usmanali

Comment: shouldn't it be `micropost.created_at.blank?` rather than `feed_post.created_at.blank?`

Comment: @MarekLipka I edited the post to make it clear that I reverted to the original code.  The question is the same as it was in the beginning.

Comment: @usmanali, you are correct, I will change it.

Comment: Do you have `kaminari` gem in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @MarekLipka, I don't have that gem but I do use 'will-paginate' gem.

Comment: No, I'm sorry for misinformation - don't show `Gemfile`. Show the source code around the error - you probably try to call `total_pages` on unpaginated relation.

Comment: @MarekLipka, I added my `Gemfile` to the post.

Comment: Ok, your `Gemfile` is correct. Show the source code around the error - I need to find out how you fetch your collection, as it's probobably incorrect.

Comment: @MarekLipka, Updated with sourcecode

Comment: It would be best if you simply show `members_controller`. Because this is where you actually fetch your collection.

Comment: @MarekLipka, I have posted the `members_controller` and the `micropost_controller` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to paginate your records using `will_paginate` in view, but you didn't paginate them in your controller:

```
def index
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Marek, thank you so much for bearing with me! Perfect! :)